# MapmyIndia map logo custom position in android app

Tags: android, mapmyindia-api

I am using mapmyindia map in my app. mapmyindia company logo is showing on bottom of map. logo got overlapped by other view on screen. I want to change logo position to make it visible. as with google map we are able to access google logo with tag and can change google logo position dynamically. Is there any way to access mapmyindia logo dynamically.

Comment: Do you had a look with LayoutInspector on the screen?

Comment: @Christopher Thanks for suggestion. it is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to access mapmyindia logo on mapmyindia map using following code.

```
View logo = ((MapmyIndiaMapView)findViewById(R.id.mapMyIndiaMapView)).getChildAt(1);
```

@Christopher comment helped me to find it using LayoutInspector.